# Why is DOM copied when I press enter key on the end of content in ContentEditable?

Tags: javascript, dom, contenteditable

While I'm making web editor with contenteditable, I met some strange action.

If I press enter key in the contenteditable element, current line's DOM is copied to next line. And then press enter key again, the DOM is copied again. 
But this situation is only occur when the caret is end of the content. Only text content does not occur by the way.
I produced this situation on latest chrome browser.

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" style="border:1px solid #000; width:500px; height:200px;">
    <p><span class="name">content</span></p>
</div>

<div id="before" style="border:1px solid blue; width:500px; height:100px;"></div>
<div id="afterEnterKeyPressed" style="border:1px solid red; width:500px; height:100px;"></div>  

$('#editor').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode === 13) {
        $('#afterEnterKeyPressed').text($('#editor').html());
    }   
});

$('#before').text($('#editor').html());
```

Here is demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qgpcdtpe/1/